# Comparing field to placeholder - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am using Go to execute a query on a PostgreSQL DB. Note that in the DB `id` is type `bigint`.

```
db.Exec("UPDATE tags SET association_count = association_count - 1 WHERE id=?;", id)
```

When I run this code, I get a SQL error

```
operator does not exist: bigint =?
```

From what I can tell this is caused by a typing mismatch between the `id` and the `?`. I've tried casting with `::` but it throws an error, and haven't found anything about this. Interestingly, if there is a space, like `id = ?` it throws a general syntax error. Any idea how to cast or work around this?

Comment: It is not a type problem. The problem is that the placeholder is not being replaced or the `id` variable value is `? `

Comment: Could the problem be the semicolon?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto What do you mean by the `id` variable value is `?`? Like Postgres doesn't know which `id` it's looking at?

Comment: I mean somehow the `id` variable has been set to `?`. Check the `db.Exec` syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres uses `$#` for placeholders [postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-prepare.html)

> When creating the prepared statement, refer to parameters by position, using $1, $2, etc. A corresponding list of parameter data types can optionally be specified. When a parameter's data type is not specified or is declared as unknown, the type is inferred from the context in which the parameter is used (if possible). When executing the statement, specify the actual values for these parameters in the EXECUTE statement. Refer to EXECUTE for more information about that.

so try

```
result, err := db.Exec(`
    UPDATE tags
    SET association_count = association_count - 1
    WHERE id=$1;`, id
)
```

Here is what [result](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Result) looks like

**UPDATE:**
*a_horse_with_no_name* makes a good point.
This depends on what client library you are using. I assumed it was **pq** since that is popular for postgres in golang.

Comment: Note that the comment from the manual refers to statement inside a procedural language e.g PL/pgSQL. The placeholder handling from a "client" language is handled by language's driver. In JDBC the placehoder _is_ `?` and `$1` wouldn't work there. So in this case apparently the driver for Go uses the same syntax as the backend. But the quote from the manual doesn't really refer to prepared statements from an application language

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thats a good point. I was assuming the OP was using pq which mimics postgres's `$1` syntax.

Comment: @poopoothegorilla another small point: you need a comma after `id` :)